# Any generic CSS libraries for web development?

Tags: css, cross-browser, styling

I'm working on a web development project where i need to take care of the design and working of the application. I found it very hard to style my UI which should be compatible will all the prominent browsers.

For example to align the text inside a div i gave

```
text-align:center
```

which worked only in IE and not in Firefox, Safari, Chrome and Opera. So i gave the Mozilla CSS style

```
text-align:-moz-center
```

which appears to fix the position only in Firefox and not in Safari, Chrome and Opera. So how to apply styles to the elements that are cross-compatible with all the browsers? Are there any CSS libraries to help us here? Any insights provided are very much appreciated.

Thank you.

NLV

Comment: This should have worked in all the browsers way back to prehistoric versions even. If it didn't, your problem is elsewhere. There are differences, of course, but they aren't this trivial.

Comment: There are several, look up blueprint. However text align works pretty standard. I believe the problem might be somewhere else. Div size? Floats?

Comment: I've a table inside a div and I've given text-align:center for the div. It is not working. Let me identify whether there are any other styles affecting this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kind-of, there is a such thing as a CSS Reset and a CSS Framework.

CSS Reset sets all default values of elements to 0 so that anything you build after that will be the same in all browsers, such as YUI Reset
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/

A framework you could use is called blueprint
http://www.blueprintcss.org/